# How to  Create DSN in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, jdbc, dsn

I want to create a `DSN` in Ubuntu Linux 10.10 for a Java application with a MySQL back end.

Sorry if the question is simple but I really need your help.

How can I create it? What are the drivers that are needed to install for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) is the way to go to get database connectivity in a Java application.

You'll need to install a JDBC driver for MySQL, e. g. [Connector/J](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Installation and usage of Connector/J is documented in [the MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j.html).

The format of a connection URL for Connector/J is specifically described in [20.3.4.1. Driver/Datasource Class Names, URL Syntax and Configuration Properties for Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).